# in css how to make a sticky navbar after the header in an hero section?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to achieve two styling at the same time, one includes a sticky position, and the other includes a parent to the sticky element :

1. I want the first part of my page, let's call it the "hero section", to take the whole screen height (this section have a `bottom` element that should be at the bottom of the screen when the page is scrolled to the top, and the rest of the content should follow after)
2. and I also want the navbar to stick to the top of the website, but this navbar is not on top of the website at the beginning (when the page is scrolled to the top), it is in second position, right after the title

additionally, I try to find a solution that does not uses javascript, **css only**.

here is a code snippet to make it clear, with two columns, one for both aspects of the problem :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.hero_bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
main {
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
section.left header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="left">
  <!-- HERO SECTION -->
  <header>
    <h1>
     either I have the "bottom" element at the bottom of the screen view...
    </h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero_bottom">hero-bottom</div>
  </header>
  <!-- end HERO SECTION -->
  <main>main content</main>
</section>

<section class="right">
  <!-- HERO SECTION -->
  <h1>
   ...or I have the navbar that stick through the entire website. But how to have both ?
  </h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="hero_bottom">hero-bottom</div>
  <!-- end HERO SECTION -->
  <main>main content</main>
</section>
```

It's easy to make the navbar sticks through the entire website if it's a direct child of the body (or any element that have the height of the website, like the `<section>` in my example), and it's easy to have the `hero-bottom` element placed at the bottom of the hero section if everything that appears at the top of the page is inside a block-level wrapper, including the navbar.

But one prevents the other : the bottom element needs the block-level wrapper, and the wrapper prevents the navbar to stick through the entire website. That's my issue !

I don't feel like there is a solution to make the navbar sticky to it's grandparent (in this situation, because I know it's sometimes possible, if you can make the parent inline-level for example), so maybe it's better to find a solution to have the `bottom` element being at the bottom of the hero section without a wrapper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, so I'll answer my own question, but it is a hacky trick, not a clean solution :/

It's a solution to the second aspect, how to place the "hero-bottom", and the rest of the page, at the bottom of the hero section, not a solution to use sticky outside the direct block-level parent

The trick is to use an invisible float element on the hero section, give it a 100vh height, and clear the main content of the page so that it follows the float element. Then, I move the "hero-bottom" part inside the main-content, and make it position absolute at the top

an example will explain it better :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
body > h1, body > nav {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
main {
  position: relative;
  height: 400vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  clear: both;
}
main .hero_bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="float"></div>
<h1>
 title
</h1>
<nav>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="hero_bottom">hero-bottom</div>
  main-content
</main>
```

However, since the hero section cannot be inside any kind of block-level element (including flexbox and grid), it's not easy to customize the position of the title and the nav bar

It's possible to use the ["clearfix" trick](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_float_clear.asp) to achieve a little bit of customization :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
header, nav {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
body * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.float_header {
  height: 60vh;
}
.float_nav {
  height: 40vh;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  position: relative;
  height: 400vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  clear: both;
}
main .hero_bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="float float_header"></div>
<header class="clearfix">
  <h1>
   title
  </h1>
</header>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="float float_nav"></div>
<nav>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="hero_bottom">hero-bottom</div>
  main-content
</main>
```

Now, I'm not sure I would use that in production

Answer (score 0):

For sticky navbar

```
<div id="navbar">Navbar</div>

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

---

For fixed element at bottom

```
<div id="bottom">bottom</botton>

#bottom{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I hope this article will help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: thank you for your answer :) your javascript solution works indeed, but it creates some bugs (a jump of the navbar, and a change of place of the bottom element). But I totally forgot to add something in my question, that I will edit now : I'm looking for a solution without javascript actually, I'm sorry I forgot to mention it :/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp read it only css

Comment: as for the element at bottom, your solution doesn't work well : the element will indeed be at the bottom, but the rest of the content does not follow anymore, since the element was removed from the document flow: But I also forgot to mention that this was important, I'll edit my question

Comment: hmm yes I have read this page already, I don't see how it is different from what I've shown in my question ?

Comment: for bottom element I wrongly used "." instead of "#"

Answer (score 0):

I would use some Javascript to achieve this. Use the setup you have in the left column. Add some script to clone the `<nav>` element and insert the copy as the first child of the body, but make it invisible to begin with. Then use an intersection observer to detect when the first section leaves the viewport; when it does, make the copied `<nav>` visible. If the user scrolls back up and the first section re-enters the viewport, make the copied `<nav>` invisible.

Comment: thank you for your answer, sorry I forgot to tell that I'm looking for a solution with css only, no javascript. I edited my question

Comment: Of course, a CSS-only solution is always preferred, but CSS can't do everything. And if you want to stick to this design, I think Javascript is the way to go. What is your reason for wanting to avoid Javascript?

Comment: Ideally, for security reason I put all the programming logic in the background, avoiding front end javascript when possible. In some situations, css only is also lighter for the browser than js, but it's not always true. In real life, I do compromise according to the time and effort I can put into the project. And in this case it's a personal project, and furthermore a small one, I want to stick to css only, at least as a training :) If the design cannot be done in css, I'll change the design, but I wanted to be sure, sometimes I just don't find the working solution myself ;)